# repeated results when grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write some code which groups sales by zone by week (see first image attached).

[image]

I've written the code below, however, it is returning repeated results eg the Category 'Misc Refrigerated Foods' appears twice on the 17th and twice on the 24th of Dec (see second screenshot attached).
[image]

Does anyone know

1) how I can amend the code so that that Category only appears once per date and 
2) how I can amend the code so that if the Category is removed from the fields selected, the Price Zone ID and Name only appear ONCE per date?

TIA.

```
Select 
    ps.PriceZoneID,
    ps.Name,
    sum (ash.Sales) as Units, 
    ash.date,  
    es.CategoryName 
FROM AggregatedSalesHistory as ash  
JOIN v_EnterpriseStructure as es ON es.ProductSID = ash.ProductSID
JOIN PriceZone as ps ON ps.PriceZoneID = ash.PriceZoneID

WHERE DepartmentName ='Dairy'
    and ash.Date >= '12-17-2014' and ash.date<= '12-31-2014' 
GROUP BY
    ps.PriceZoneID,
    ps.Name,
    es.CategoryName,
    ash.Sales, 
    ash.Date
```

Comment: Remove `ash.sales` from your `GROUP BY`. Putting a column you are aggregating in your `GROUP BY` renders the aggregation pointless. (For example, the `SUM` of the values `289` is `289`; as it's the **only** value)

Comment: Ah, cool! Thanks Larnu! Removing ash.sales from the GROUP BY made it work! However, if I removed es.CategoryName from the GROUP BY I get an error that says "Column 'v_EnterpriseStructure.CategoryName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." Do you know how I can remove Category Name from the GROUP BY but still return aggregated results by zone and date? TIA.

Comment: On a different note, for further questions, make sure you don't post your data as an image, and especially not your code; other users can't interact with it and most likely why your question was downvoted.

Comment: Remove `es.CategoryName ` from your `SELECT`? The error is literally telling you the error here.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks for letting me know! I'd originally copied the text from Excel but the format wasn't good when I pasted it here - hence the reason I attached an image - to make it as easy as possible for someone to see what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Aha! Got it! Thanks for your help and the prompt responses! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

One option would be simply choosing the rows with the maximum amount of units.

```
select p.PriceZoneID, p.Name, max(p.Units) as Units, p.Date, p.CategoryName 
from
(
    Select 
        ps.PriceZoneID,
        ps.Name,
        sum (ash.Sales) as Units, 
        ash.date,  
        es.CategoryName 
    FROM AggregatedSalesHistory as ash  
    JOIN v_EnterpriseStructure as es ON es.ProductSID = ash.ProductSID
    JOIN PriceZone as ps ON ps.PriceZoneID = ash.PriceZoneID

    WHERE DepartmentName ='Dairy'
        and ash.Date >= '12-17-2014' and ash.date<= '12-31-2014' 
    GROUP BY
        ps.PriceZoneID,
        ps.Name,
        es.CategoryName,
        ash.Sales, 
        ash.Date
) p
group by p.PriceZoneID, p.Name, p.Date, p.CategoryName 
--If category isn't there remove the field and the group by category
```